# Javascript RegEx: Get 1 or 2 digits after a symbol (Excluding that symbol)

Tags: javascript, regex

Thanks in advance for taking a look at this. I'm having some difficulty extracting something to create a sports project. I've got the following situation:

> lastName, firstName #33 6

Which works fine with the following:

```
var number = $(this).text().match(/\d{1,2}/);
```

But, if I use it for the following (missing the number) than it's grabbing the 6, because obviously I am searching for one or two digits.

> lastName, firstName # 6

Basically what I'm trying to do is pull in a one or two digit number after the number sign (if there is one) but ignore anything that comes after it and before it (# included). I'm not extremely handy with RegEx so hopefully one of you are able to understand what I mean by this.

Comment: You mean like this? `#\d*`
You can cut out he `#`afterwards.

Comment: It's a shame Javascript doesn't allow look-behinds - `(?<!#)\d+` would work perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

Try: `#(\d{1,2})`

You can use capture groups in JS (from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/432493/how-do-you-access-the-matched-groups-in-a-javascript-regular-expression))

```
var myString = "something format_abc";
var myRegexp = /(?:^|\s)format_(.*?)(?:\s|$)/g;
var match = myRegexp.exec(myString);
alert(match[1]);
```

---

To allow spaces between # and number: `#\s*(\d{1,2})`

`\s*` will catch all the spaces.

Comment: Thanks for the response. That will still catch the 6, no? I probably could have worded my question better, but I'm trying to capture only numbers directly after the #, so like the 33 in my first example. I'm trying to ignore the 6 in the second example because it doesn't come directly after the #.

Answer (score 0):

There seems to be no leading 0 possible, so I added that restriction and also the number has to be followed by a whitespace or it has to be a the end.

```
var re = /#\s*([1-9][0-9]?)(?:\s|$)/;
var matches = [];
var str = '...';
while ((match = re.exec(str)) != null) {
    matches.push(match[1]);
}
```